# Finding all real numbers x such that $x \lceil x \lceil x \lceil x \rceil \rceil \rceil = 88$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

**Question:**

> Find all real numbers x such that $x \lceil x \lceil x \lceil x \rceil \rceil \rceil = 88$.

The notation $\lceil x \rceil$ means: The least integer which is not less than $x$.

**My ideas:**

Let's say $\lceil x\rceil=y$ is an integer. If we find $y$ then we'd be able to say $y-1 < x < y$. With this, $y \lceil y \lceil y \lceil y \rceil \rceil \rceil = 88 \to y^4 = 88$, which has no integer solutions.

Am I approaching it wrongly? Where do I start?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation). For this question, the commands `\lfloor` and `\rfloor` are of particular interest, since they represent the standard floor brackets:
$$\lfloor x \rfloor = \min \{ k\in\mathbb Z \mid k \ge x\}$$

Comment: @AlexR, I think we want the ceiling function here

Comment: @doeo Thanks for pointing that out :) Since I can't edit that anymore, the actual commands are `\lceil` and `\rceil`.

Comment: Your idea doesn't make sense to me: you can't have both $x=y$ and $x<y$.

Comment: I see, it is corrected now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no number $x$ for which $f(x)=x[x[x[x]]]$ equals $88$.

$f(x)$ is an increasing function over $\mathbb{R}^+$ and:

$$ f(3)=81,\qquad \lim_{x\to 3^+} f(x) = 120. $$

$f(x)$ is a decreasing function over $(-\infty,-1]$ and:
$$ f(-3) = 81, \qquad \lim_{x\to -3^-}f(x) = 90.$$

Comment: A tiny gap here: $f(x)$ is not an increasing function for negative $x$...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: fixed.

Comment: An explanation of this calculation: if $x>3$, then $[x]\geq 4$, so $x[x]>12$, so $[x[x]]\geq 13$, so $x[x[x]]>3*13=39$, so $x[x[x[x]]]>3*40.$

Comment: @Aaron: At least when I was in school/IMO training $[3+\epsilon]=3$ for all $\epsilon\in(0,1)$. The floor function has become more common since, but at that time the typewriters didn't have that symbol. Square bracket was available, though.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was using the notation that Jack and the (pre-edit) question used:$[x]$ for the least integer greater than or equal to $x$.

Comment: @Aaron Strange, I have never seen the square bracket to mean the ceiling function. I guess anything is possible, but... Shrug.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Yeah, it's nonstandard (and $[x]$ usually means $\lfloor x \rfloor$ if it means one of the two), but the author clearly defined his notation, so I went with it.  It was probably an issue of not knowing the proper LaTeX.

Comment: Oops You're right @Aaron. It is possible that I had too much faith in my interpretation. Let's wait for the OP to comment. ALL: Sorry about being pushy. I assumed that the more common meaning of $[x]$ was intended, and the editor changed the meaning of the question. gt6989b seems to have interpretede it the same way I did. Waiting for the OP to confirm.

Comment: I believe there was some misunderstanding, it should read "the least integer which is not less than x". New here so I'm still learning the character/symbol stuff

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @user253171. In that case this answer is correct, and my calculation goes to `/dev/null`. No harm. Sorry about creating confusion.

Comment: All good, any help or contributions we can learn of is appreciated! Is it thus sufficient to show this ^ answer as proof to the question? Seeing that when expressed as a function (in this case) we can't reach the desired conditions?

Answer (score 6):

**hint**

Note that if $x=3$, then $x^4=81<88$ and if $x=4$ then $x^4 = 256 > 88$. So you want to find numbers closer to $3$. What happens, for example, if you look at $x = 3.1$ or $3.05$? PLaying with these should give you an idea...